# Get info from table of specific position td with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hello I have a tbody html with various tr and tds inside them, and i want to extract always the 3,7,11 td position inside every tr, how can i do that?

I want to extract from X row inside table, value of position td 1 7 and 11 of every row.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give a minimal example of the HTML source?

Comment: you could `find_all()` of those td tags and then just index into the ones you want

Comment: Please post your code, what you have tried so far? Are you looking for selenium solution or beautifulsoup slotion?

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this in selenium works,

```
how_many_tr = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'table tbody tr')

for i in range(len(how_many_tr)):
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,f'table/tbody/tr[{i}]/td[1]').text
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,f'table/tbody/tr[{i}]/td[7]').text
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,f'table/tbody/tr[{i}]/td[11]').text
```

Comment: that code does not iterate trough all the rows in the table and how im gonna put a integer inside len? thanks

Comment: @JavierDecenaCastillo, can you give me the HTML code of the table. I think I can help more in that.